# Redirect batch of urls from routes.rb

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, routes, seo, yaml

For SEO purpose, I have to redirect bunch of urls (something like 200) for now, maybe more later, maybe less.
I want to have easy access to it. So I thought about having a dedicated file containing all urls I need to redirect.
Something like

```
# config/seo_redirection_table.yml

- old_path: '/old/path/1'
  new_path: '/new_path_1'
  status: 301 
- old_path: '/old/path/2'
  new_path: '/new_path_2'
  status: 301
```

And then in my `routes.rb` mapping this file at the very top. 
Is it a good practice ? What do you think ? And how can I handle this logic in my `routes.rb`.

Comment: If these are static paths, I'd use a Rack middleware to handle it (instead of `routes.rb`).

Comment: @Stefan I'd like to have it in yml

Comment: The middleware could read the redirects from a yml file.

Comment: How you cloud do this @Stefan ?

Comment: [Rails 4, Rack, Middleware, Redirect](https://medium.com/@paulskarseth/rails-4-rack-middleware-redirect-5f48d4dd76d0) looks like a good start.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you'd like to have your redirect rules within your code base, your approach is fine. Since the rules are static you can load them upon routes creation:

```
# config/routes.rb

require 'yaml'

Rails.application.routes.draw do
  redirects = YAML.load_file('config/redirects.yml')
  redirects.each do |rule|
    get rule["old_path"], to: redirect(rule["new_path"], status: rule["status"])
  end

  # other routes
end
```

You may also consider using a library:

- https://github.com/vigetlabs/redirector: Rack middleware which loads redirect definitions from a database. Advantage: you may update your redirection rules without code changes.
- https://github.com/jtrupiano/rack-rewrite: Rack redirection middleware. It allows you to either redirect or rewrite requests.

Answer (score 0):

You could do it in routes.rb like so:

```
get '/old/path/:id', to: redirect('/new_path_%{id}', status: 301)
```

So you don't need to create a lot of static routes and one test will be enough instead to write tests for the static routes.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I want to have it in a dedicated yml file, as I could iterate over it and match potential redirect. There isnt any pattern or particular relation between old_url and new_url and I don't want to write `get '/old/path/:id', to: redirect('/new_path_%{id}', status: 301)` 200 times :)